# there is no error but data didn't inserted

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Data is not inserting into table (codeigniter), all the field names are correct as in the view and database table.

This is my model

```
public function Insert() {
    $data = array(
        'Package_id'     => $this->input->get_post('package_id'),
        'cab_id'         => $this->input->get_post('cab_id'),
        'customer_name'  => $this->input->get_post('customer_name'),
        'customer_contact'=> $this->input->get_post('customer_contact'),
        'customer_email' => $this->input->get_post('customer_email'),
        'gender'         => $this->input->get_post('gender'),
        'no_of_seats'    => $this->input->get_post('no_of_seats'));
    $this->db->insert('booking',$data);
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

This is my controller

```
public function Insert() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');         
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_name','Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_seats','Number Of Seats','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_contact','Contact Number','required|exact_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender','Gender','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_email','Email ID','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('booking_date','Date','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_address','Address','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->model('BookingModel');
        if($this->BookingModel->Insert()) {
            die('<div class="alert alert-success">Successfully Booked!</div><script>$("#response")[0].reset()</script>');
        } else {
            die('<div class="alert alert-danger">Failed to Book try again!</div>');
        }
    } else {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the table definition please

Comment: You are not really loking for errors. Did you check all the error log?

Comment: USE $this->input->post() instead of $this->input->get_post

Comment: Try with $this->input->post_get('some_data', TRUE);

Comment: `print_r($data)` and turn `db_debug` to on in database.php

Comment: `$this->input->post('package_id')` use `post()` instead of `get_post()`. Show ur your table schema.

Comment: get_post() works only for GET request, here you are sending by POST method. This should also work $this->input->post('some_data'); OR post_get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have some syntax errors. Try the below. Make note of the change to package_id in the key in data.

```
    $data = array(
    'package_id'     => $this->input->post('package_id'), // Lowercase the package id!!
    'cab_id'         => $this->input->post('cab_id'),
    'customer_name'  => $this->input->post('customer_name'),
    'customer_contact'=> $this->input->post('customer_contact'),
    'customer_email' => $this->input->post('customer_email'),
    'gender'         => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'no_of_seats'    => $this->input->post('no_of_seats')   
);

$res = $this->db->insert('booking',$data);

if ($res->affected_rows() == 1){
    echo "Wohoo!";
} else {
    echo "Back to StackOverflow..";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
//controller
  if($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->model('BookingModel');
$data = array(
        'Package_id'     => $this->input->get_post('package_id'),
        'cab_id'         => $this->input->get_post('cab_id'),
        'customer_name'  => $this->input->get_post('customer_name'),
        'customer_contact'=> $this->input->get_post('customer_contact'),
        'customer_email' => $this->input->get_post('customer_email'),
        'gender'         => $this->input->get_post('gender'),
        'no_of_seats'    => $this->input->get_post('no_of_seats'));
        if($this->BookingModel->Insert($data)) {
            die('<div class="alert alert-success">Successfully Booked!</div><script>$("#response")[0].reset()</script>');
        } else {
            die('<div class="alert alert-danger">Failed to Book try again!</div>');
        }
    } else {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}  

//model
 function Insert($data) {
    if ($this->db->insert('booking', $data)) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    return 0;
    }
```